# Can anyone explain to me explain to me what Robert Pirsig is trying to convey through the book ZAMM as a whole?

Tags: metaphysics

I feel that trying to go about analyzing his whole theory is pointless since his whole theory builds upon one point which is that analytical thinking shouldn't have taken the front seat in modern culture (as he goes on ranting about Aristotle and so forth), but is anything to be gained by applying the analytical "knife" on his theory of Quality ?

[What does Pirsig mean by "Quality"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30747/what-does-pirsig-mean-by-quality)

I read this above question before posting here. I'm trying to understand what is he really trying to get at in the book as a whole.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I went through that before posting it myself. What I'm trying to ask is different from that question. I'm trying to understand what is Pirsig trying to drive at in the book as a whole. Not just by notion of Quality.

Comment: Definitely going to reread it, but from my faint memory Pirsig is coming to terms with the gap between good rhetorical practice and effective living and thinking; a gap exacerbated by his struggles with high-functioning mental health issues.

Comment: What does a novel, a fictionalized autobiography in this case, is usually trying to get at? Present a story, expose character's personality, educate and/or impart practical wisdom to the reader, promote the author's system of beliefs and values, a way of  and attitude towards life, and so on. Pirsig's Quality is not dissimilar to Tao and embodies both metaphysical and ethical dimensions, so if the analytical knife is applied it should be done while respecting that what is on the table is not a "theory", but a literary/philosophical text.